# input box filled with barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, barcode-scanner

I have input box which can be filled from barcode scanner input.

```
 <input type="text"  autofocus class="form-control m-input" id="productSearch" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Product name">
```

But the problem is whenever the input box filled with input it should make empty and add relevant value to table. 
I have used following function to do that. The relevant value automatically added  to table but the problem is it also showing autosuggestion. How do i stop showing autosuggestion as well as make the value empty.

```
$("#productSearch").keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '10' || event.which == '13') {
    // alert(this.value)
    $.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "{!! asset('searchByProductName') !!}",
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        name: this.value
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // console.log(response)
        if ($('#' + response.id).length !== 0)
          return;

        var markup = "<tr id=" + response.id + "><input type='hidden' name='product_id[]'  value=" + response.id + "><td><i class='flaticon-delete-1 delete-row' onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td><td>" + response.product_name + "</td><td>" + response.product_unit_price + "</td><td><input type='text' name='quantity[]' class='quantity' value='1'></td><td class='total'>" + response.product_unit_price + "</td><td>" + response.notes + "</td></tr>";

        $("table tbody").append(markup);
        calculateSum();

        $('.quantity').on('keyup', function() {
          var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
          var col3 = currentRow.find("td:eq(2)").text();
          var data = col3 * $(this).val();
          currentRow.find("td:eq(4)").text(data.toFixed(2))
          calculateSum();
        });

        $(this).val("");
        return false;
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Here to mention. if barcode scanner couldn't find value i have implemented autosuggestion with the above input box as well.

Answer (score 0):

Barcode scanner works like a keyboard. It is a text input device. Write a function to the text change event of your text box. check the length of the string and call a function to add string to the database and clear the text field.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off autocomplete

```
<input type="text"  autofocus class="form-control m-input" id="productSearch" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Product name" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: i can't stop autocomplete ..as if the barcode scanner can't read the input i need to type it manually where autocomplete suggestion is needed